# Spoiler Tags not working in answer that contains Right-To-Left (Hebrew) text

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown

I made an answer here:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5041/5474

And the spoiler tags do not seem to work on the paragraph that contains the Hebrew text. I have tried changing the formatting and moving the paragraphs but nothing seems to work. Is this a bug in SE?

**EDIT:** I was able to get the whole answer enclosed in spoiler tags, but I can't seem to get the formatting right. (There are no line breaks.) I must have something wrong in the Markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it for you by adding <P> tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what revision(s) of the answer you're talking about, so I may be off the mark. **You cannot have multiple consecutive paragraphs in spoiler markup**. (You can have line breaks inside a spoiler paragraph, however.)

This is by design: if you have a large, multi-paragraph block of spoiler text, you're hiding too much. You should only hide actual spoilers, not your whole answer. I can't find an officially [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) report on that, only a statement that “[it's not fully classified a bug as much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144824/consecutive-spoiler-blocks-are-shown-as-blockquotes#comment788327_144824)” and “[That's somewhere between a bug and a feature request then. It's kind of by design, but more of the "because that's how it works" variety.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112793/paragraphs-breaks-are-ignored-inside-spoilers#comment292848_112793)” in one of the [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105735/how-can-i-put-a-whole-code-block-in-spoiler-text) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-format-well) [similar](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/spoiler-issues-in-editing) [issues](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2101/spoiler-markdown-issue-with-multiple-paragraphs) have been reported.

There is a workaround, which is to use `<p>` tags for a paragraph break. This works by happenstance, not by design; I wouldn't recommend relying on it.